# Select records from SQL in specifics months

Tags: php, sql, records

I need to get from table posts records from specific month in Unix time, row Date is unixtime and input to function is unixtime too. Something like:

```
Select * from `posts` where FROM_UNIXTIME(date, month) = FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp, month);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean: march -> all records "from" march 2013 and march 2014 and march 2015 or are those three seperate results (i.e. your query would be "select march 2014")?

Comment: @VolkerK, do I know you from TMC?

Comment: @Chuck, I don't think so. The only TMC I know of is the "Traffic Message Channel" ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK , Thanks, the other Volker is from TeslaMotorsClub.

Comment: yes, as said Volkerk